# Send value to another file JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want send the value of this two variables to another js file. How can I do it?

```
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/login');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.get('/auth', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/login/index.html'));   
});
var username;
var password;

app.post('/userAuth', function(request, response) {
    username = request.body.username;
    password = request.body.password;
    response.end();
});
```

Comment: export a function in the other file and send the data as a param to the function in another js file

Comment: Can you show me a example?

Comment: see the example below in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the function in another file. Say you want to send data to func2.js

```
//func2.js
    exports.login = (data) => {
        console.log(data.username);
    }
```

You can call send the data as follows from func1.js

```
//func1.js
const func2 = require('./func2');
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/login');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.get('/auth', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/login/index.html'));   
});
var username;
var password;

app.post('/userAuth', function(request, response) {
    username = request.body.username;
    password = request.body.password;
    var data = {
       username:username,
       password:password
    }
    func2.login(data);
    response.end();
});
```